# Why when I use input tag type number it's able to write "e" character inside the text

Tags: html

Why when I use input tag type number it's able to write "e" character inside the text?

---

```html
<input type="number">
```

Comment: Probable because "e" is a part of exponent notation, where the number before the  `e` is multiplied by 10 to the power of the number after `e`.  For example `5e2 =  5 * (10 ^ 2) = 5 * 100 = 500`

Comment: It actually allows every charcater. But it depends on how the browser interprets it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MDN web docs on 
`<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)
:

> They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical entries.

and

> Note: Browsers that don't support type "number" fall back to using a standard "text" input.

That means if the browser supports the value "number" for the attribute "type", it generally implements some kind of validation, like a red border around the field. But it depends on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number">
```

> Yes

It allows "e" for if "e" is a part of exponent notation